# Wired ethernet connection not working after suspend on Debian

Tags: debian, ethernet, wired-networking, debian-jessie, wired

I have been using Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) for over a year on my laptop. Since the last update the wired Ethernet connection is not working after the system resumes from hibernating. Restarting the system fixes the issue. 
Is there a way to reactivate networking without having to restart the system?

There is [a related question (but for wifi) concerning Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: Does the cable replugging solve the problem?

Comment: No, only a restart solves the problem.

Comment: This problem only occurred after a software update. So I may close the question now.

Comment: @PaulRougieux Which software? Did you end up solving your problem somehow? Running `sudo service network-manager restart` after resume solves it for me but it's kind of hackish...

Comment: I meant after an automated update of several packages on Debian. I didn't keep track of which software were updated. I guess you could check the Debian update log for which packages were updated in the few dates before I asked my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too. In my case it is a trouble with the `rtl8169` driver and suspend/resume.

As root (check that r8169 is loaded first):

```
root@asus:/var/log# lsmod |grep r8169
r8169                  94208  0
mii                    16384  1 r8169
```

As root:

```
rmmod r8169
modprobe r8169
```

And wait a little bit (it could include restarting networking)

Answer (score 0):

In debian you can edit `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/hdparm` (in Arch it's `/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/hdparm`) and add these lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "${1}" == "pre" ]; then
  # Do the thing you want before suspend here, e.g.:
    sudo modprobe -r r8168
elif [ "${1}" == "post" ]; then    
    sudo modprobe r8168
fi
```

This will disable the card at suspend time and re-enable it on resume forcing it to reinitialize.
I am using r8168 drivers. If you use a different driver simply replace r8168 in the script with your driver name